# Windows 8.1 Pro Pack on a new computer

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

I have received a replacement computer that has Windows 8.1 pre-installed. The previous computer stopped working and has been destroyed.

I have gone to upgrade it to Windows 8.1 Pro and it accepted the product key but the next day it won't allow me to activate Windows because the product key is in use on another computer.

How do I somehow notify that the previous computer is no longer a computer (it's probably in a thousand pieces by now) and that I am correctly licensed and should be allowed to activate it on this replacement computer.

Comment: Yes, that's what Pro Pack is used for, and I have mentioned that in the title as well as the question.

Comment: What is confusing you about "upgrade it to Windows 8.1 Pro"? Forget your answer, you'll loose the rep not me ;-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Microsoft usually provides an alternative method to activate copies of Windows that have been flagged as in use on another computer, usually by phoning Microsoft and activating over the phone. Your activation screen should have this option on the same page that tells you it is in use. For example, on the following screen, click Call Support:

[image]

http://www.eightforums.com/installation-setup/41010-windows-8-pro-license-transfer-new-windows-8-1-computer.html#post343592

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, the Windows licenses won't work anymore if there is a hardware change. Note that this doesn't apply to RAM and HDD/SSD, but since you said the previous computers is in bits and pieces by now, Windows will only recognise that one for being the first and sole beneficiarry of the license.

You could try and take it up to them, but from my experience with others in the same position, that won't do you any good either.

Comment: I am talking about the Pro Pack upgrade product key which is not supplied tied to a particular computer.