# Windows 8.1 Display Language

Tags: windows-8.1

I have a windows 8.1 new machine with arabic language pack, but I still see some areas still using English as language, i.e. control panel, store, search, help notes. Other apps are displayed in arabic.

[This page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/language-packs#lptabs=win8) mention that arabic can have any language as base language, and the license is I have is 8.1 Single Language. Does base language mean I can set arabic as base language ? or it seems I must still have unicode (i.e english) as base language ?

Comment: Windows 8.1 Single Language installations cannot install multiple language packs.  One solution is to upgrade to a Windows 8.1 Professional with Media Center via the Windows 8.1 Pro Pack thus allowing you to install additional language packs.

Comment: I appreciate if you can give some detailed steps ? It's my first time to use windows since windows xp and the UI is little bit confusing to me. Where should I go to do the upgrade ?

Comment: It is a paid upgrade. [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/927016/windows-8-1-pro-pack-on-a-new-computer/927165#927165) is an answer I proposed to another similar question as your comment

Comment: that question says that I can recover windows and install arabic language without english ?

Comment: The only language pack you can use is Arabic unless you upgrade to Windows 8.1 Professional with Media Center via the Windows 8.1 Pro Pack.  How complete the Arabic is I cannot comment on, but English, isn't a "base language" though.  Different languages have different levels of coverage.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I went through recovery and I did windows reset from factory settings. I found in the first screen during setup the machine that I have to choose betwen arabic or english and that I need to carefully pick the language as I cannot change it later on. Now I am done with reinstall windows and everything now is in Arabic. :) Thanks again!